# Get all documents from collection on Firestore and store into array then print fields

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the documents from a collection on firestore and display the fields in a h1 tag, however, the code below keeps fetching the data (was only supposed to fetch once) and the content is not populating in the h1. The data does get stored in the subjects array but I can't seem to get the data to display.

**Firestore Connection**

```
export const db = firebase.firestore();
```

**Subjects File**

```
  export default function Subjects() {

  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSubjects(){
      const data = []
      await db.collection("Subjects").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            data.push(doc.data());
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });

      setSubjects(data);
      console.log(subjects);
    }

    fetchSubjects();
  });

  return(
    <>
      {subjects.map(subject =>(
        <h1 key={subject.title}>{subject.title}</h1>
      ))}
    </>
  );

};
```

**Calling Subjects Component in Separate Page**

```
<Subjects/>
```

**Below, you can see that the data keeps getting fetched**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is behaving like that because you have not passed second argument in `useEffect`.

What you might do is add `[]` as second argument to only execute `useEffect` on first render.

```js
useEffect(() => {}, []);
```

And also, you are using `then` with `await` which might not work as `await` expects a promise. So in this case you might want to remove the `then` part or you can set the state inside `then` function.

1. Without async/await

```js
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('Subjects')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            const data = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
                data.push(doc.data());
            });
            setSubjects(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
        });
}, []);
```

2. With async/await

```js
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchSubjects() {
        const data = []
        const querySnapshot = await db.collection("Subjects").get();
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            data.push(doc.data());
        });

        setSubjects(data);
    }

    fetchSubjects();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to stop the constant fetching. The only issue I'm currently running into is that the page is rendering before the data can be fetched so the data doesn't appear when it renders. Do you possibly have a solution to this?